# How to make an application with editable structure of database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, data-structures

I need to create an application with an **editable database structure**. Where you can ***add/delete/modify*** **tables and fields**, **views** and structure of the **database**. All in production and real time.

The purpose is that the application can be adapted to the needs of the company. Allowing you to store the information that is needed, where it is needed.

I use laravel 5 and MySQL, but my question is not about my software. My questions are:

- Is there a methodology, or a set of steps to follow, to achieve this functionality?
- And if it exists, is there any package to apply it to laravel?

Comment: This question is way to broad, to give you an good answer..

Comment: Maybe you should look at [Graph database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) or other NoSQL databases. Because relational DB's are optimized for static data structures. (Think also that you will need to create indexes and many other stuff dynamically - is it worth it with SQL ?)

Comment: Is your goal creating a laravel-phpmyadmin sort-of-thing?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is the application, and for the administrators, a tool that allows him to add functionalities, like to store more data objects in new table, to **add fields** to an existing object. And their respective **forms** to create the info and see it. I know that it means modify the DB in production, create dinamical views, edit permisions, models and migrations in hot... But there must be a way to do it, or at least I should be able to try it.

Answer (score 1):

[Entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model allows to have a DB with something like a "dynamic schema" and be able to run indexed queries on its tables (though "tables" become different from what you would have if you used the normal approach). With it you can add and remove fields and have the values indexed (unlike in a document-oriented NoSQL DB). Downsides: a lot of joins, performance might suffer; however, I've seen pretty large systems get away with it. Don't know if and how it can be applied in Laravel context, but googling gives at least some results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Business Intelligence and reporting tools, which fulfil all your needs. They run with any db, no matter which fields you add or remove they will adjust themselves. One of the best example is:-

https://github.com/getredash/redash